# How to stop in a breakpoint after x passes in Pycharm?

Tags: debugging, pycharm, breakpoints

Within Visual Studio, I can determine for the debug to stop at a breakpoint only after a specific number of times the program passes through it.

However, I can not find the same inside Pycharm.

Would anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a breakpoint at your desired position. Use hotkey `ctrl`,`shift`,`F8` to open the "View Breakpoints" window. There you can mark the checkbox "condition".

In case you want to stop the program in a loop after 5 iterations, you can set the condition to `target==5`, where `target` is part of the loop as follows:

```
for target in object:
    <your loop body>
```

and `object` is your iterable.

Comment: So, I have to create an additional code inside my current code to get this?

Comment: No, you set a conditional breakpoint, which only fires when a certain condition is met (i.e. returns `True`) And this condition is a python expression like e.g. `target == 5`